# Flutter/Dart get Function arg type without mirrors

Tags: generics, flutter, dart

So I need to determine the type of a callback function's arg.

Here is a test that demonstrates the absence of usable type information.

```
void main() {
  Tester().test();
}

class A {}

class B extends A {}

class Tester {
  void test() {
    // pass a function that takes B as an arg
    on((B arg) {});
  }

  void on<T extends A>(Function(T value) listener) {
    Type type = T.runtimeType;
    if (type is B) {
      print("It worked");
    } else {
      print("Doh, type is $type");
      print("${listener.runtimeType}");
    }
  }
}
```

here is the output

> I/flutter (26001): Doh, type is _Type
>
> I/flutter (26001): (B) => Null

Answer (score 0):

So here is a working solution :)

```
void main() {
  Tester().test();
}

class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

class D {}

class I<T> {}

class Tester {
  void test() {
    on2((B arg) {}, B());
    on2((A arg) {}, B());
    on2((C arg) {}, B());
    on2((C arg) {}, C());

    // Type checking in dart doesn't prevent using D (it should), but we have a runtime check on the on2 method
    on2((D arg) {}, C());
  }

  void on2<O extends A, E extends A>(Function(O value) listener, E emit) {
    var t1 = I<O>();
    var t2 = I<E>();
    if (t1.runtimeType == t2.runtimeType) {
      print("$t1 == $t2");
    }

    // catch function with type that doesn't extend A
    if (t1.runtimeType.toString().toLowerCase().contains("null")) {
      print("INvalid type $t1");
    }
  }
}
```

The output...

> I/flutter (26219): Instance of 'I' == Instance of 'I'
>
> I/flutter (26219): Instance of 'I' == Instance of 'I'
>
> I/flutter (26219): INvalid type Instance of 'I'

Comment: This solution turns out to be unreliable, sometimes the type is the base type instead.